# Can I swap the SSD from mid-2013 Macbook Air and mid-2014 Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I bought a Macbook Air with a 256 GB in mid 2013.

I bought a Macbook Pro with a 128 GB in mid 2014.

I'd like to swap the SSDs if possible. Are the parts compatible?

I'm looking at these two guides on [iFixit](http://ifixit.com).

- [Macbook Air 13" Mid-2013 SSD replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/15181)
- [Macbook Pro 13" Mid-2014 SSD replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27849)

The parts **look** compatible, but I'd like to a little further confirmation before dissecting both of the laptops.

---

**Additional info**

I just did a speed test on each drive.

```
                  Model      Read        Write       Vendor
Macbook Air 13"   Mid-2013   ~750 MB/s   ~700 MB/s   Samsung/Samsung
Macbook Pro 13"   Mid-2014   ~750 MB/s   ~350 MB/s   Sandisk/Marvell
```

The Macbook Air's SSD has **double** the write speed! So if it works, I have even more (than disk capacity) to gain from making the swap.

Makes me really sad that Apple isn't more specific with these details on their website.

**Tools required**

```
              Security Bits
Macbook Air   P5 Pentalobe, T5 Torx
Macbook Pro   T5 Torx
```

I ordered the [iFixit 54-Bit Driver Kit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/54-Bit-Driver-Kit/IF145-022) which includes the tools I'll need to try this.

I'll post the results here once I attempt the surgery!

Answer (score 2):

**It doesn't work**

My Pentalobe and Torx bits arrived today and I tried swapping the drives. When I put the 256 GB drive in my Macbook Pro, it doesn't boot and displays this image

[image: cannot boot]

I tried holding down <kbd>opt</kbd> to boot to a usb drive and do a fresh install of Mavericks on the drive.

When I attempt to boot from the USB drive, the crossed out circle image is displayed again.

I've also tried holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> during boot to boot into safe mode. The neutral gray screen displays for a longer time, but eventually the crossed out circle appears again.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [well-respected and detailed guide](https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades) to Apple's SSD modules, the mid-2013 MBA and mid-2014 MBP use the same 'Generation 3' SSD module.

They should therefore work in both machines. The fact that you get the same "No Entry" sign when using an external USB suggests that there's some other problem. Conceivably, that could be caused by not inserting the SSD completely/properly.

Answer (score 0):

how is it going?
I hope you were able to fix the issue you were experiencing, I'm sure you didn't push the SSD all he way in. I swapped the SSD between the two Macs myself and it was very smooth. Hit me up if you need any help.

Comment: Which two models did you swap between?

Answer (score -1):

Restart computer hold CMD+R it will boot into recovery 
Click reinstall OS X